# sort table using $_get['sort'] , error Unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, html, sorting

I tried to sort a table by clicking the th of the table using $_get['sort'] function

this is my code

```
<?php
//connect to server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

//connect to database
//select the database
mysql_select_db("fak_databases");

//submit button
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $country = $_POST['country'];
}

//query the database
if($country == TRUE) {  
    // query to get all AL records  
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='$country'");  
    if ($_GET['sort'] == 'city')
    {
        $query .= " ORDER BY wipo_applicant1_city";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'address')
    {
        $query .= " ORDER BY applicant1_addr1";
    }
}  

//fetch the result
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<th><a href="showDB.php?sort=city">City</a></th>";
Print "<th><a href="showDB.php?sort=address">Address</a></th>";
Print "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<td>".$row['wipo_applicant1_city'] . "</td>"; 
    Print "<td>".$row['applicant1_addr1'] . " </td></tr>"; 
}

Print "</table>";
?>
```

but I got an error

```
syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

which the line is

```
Print "<th><a href="showDB.php?sort=city">City</a></th>";
```

anyone can fix this issue?

and  I need to be able to click head table and sort alphabetically...

and I have a question, is $_get['sort'] function only sort ascending??or both ascending and descending?? if only sort ascending, is any function that can sort ascending and descending while I click on the table head??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are not escaping your double quotes and hence PHP ends the string where it encounters second double quote in your string

```
Print "<th><a href=\"showDB.php?sort=city\">City</a></th>";
                ---^---               ---^---
```

OR use `'` quotes around your string, you can us this safely here as you are not having any variables inside your string

```
print '<th><a href="showDB.php?sort=city">City</a></th>';
```

I would suggest you, not to print HTML using PHP, just separate them like

```
<table border cellpadding=3>
  <tr>
     <th><a href="showDB.php?sort=city">City</a></th>
     <th><a href="showDB.php?sort=address">Address</a></th>
  </tr>
<?php
  //PHP Code Here
?>
<!-- HTML Here Again -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use double quotes in way you did this. It should be:

```
Print '<th><a href="showDB.php?sort=city">City</a></th>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
   <?php
  //connect to server
   $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

 //connect to database
 //select the database
  mysql_select_db("fak_databases");

 //submit button
   if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
   {
  $country = $_POST['country'];
   }

  //query the database
   if($country == TRUE) {  
 // query to get all AL records  
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE    applicant1_country='$country'");  
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'city')
{
    $query .= " ORDER BY wipo_applicant1_city";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'address')
{
    $query .= " ORDER BY applicant1_addr1";
}
 }  

//fetch the result
   Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";
  Print "<tr>";
  Print '<th><a href="showDB.php?sort=city">City</a></th>';
  Print '<th><a href="showDB.php?sort=address">Address</a></th>';
  Print "</tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {

Print "<tr>";
Print "<td>".$row['wipo_applicant1_city'] . "</td>"; 
Print "<td>".$row['applicant1_addr1'] . " </td></tr>"; 
  }

Print "</table>";
 ?>
```

Comment: When answering, it helps if you explain what you changed, and why you changed it - just so you know!